# Cannot cycle through all pixels of rectangular image matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I am attempting to increase brightness of the loaded image `img`, however to cycle through the pixels i am using a smaller matrix [which i will use to apply Gaussian blur later]. Here is my function:

```
void Dobright(cv::Mat &in,IplImage * img)
{   
    uchar* temp_ptr ;
    for( int row = 0; row < in.rows; row++) 
    {
            for ( int col = 0; col < in.cols; col++) 
            {
                CvPoint pt = {row,col};
                temp_ptr  = &((uchar*)(img->imageData + img->widthStep*pt.y))[pt.x*3];
                temp_ptr[0] += 100;
                temp_ptr[1] += 100;
                temp_ptr[2] += 100;
            }
    }
}
```

However if the original image was:

[image]

I get the brightened image as:

[image]

As you can see some parts are brighter than the others and since rows and columns are not same hence the pixels of entire image is not accessed, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know that there are OpenCV functions for applying Gaussian blur, as well as a function to scale matrices? (for example cv::Mat::convert())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the looks of it you have width and height mixed up, try using:
`CvPoint pt = {col,row};`

also with your current algorithm you will run into problems when your pixels original values are > 155, (156 + 100 = 1) because of rounding. Try using

`tmp_ptr[0] = (tmp_ptr > 155) ? 255 : tmp_ptr[0] + 100;`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've flipped your x and y here.  You want the CvPoint to be `{col,row}` not `{row,col}`.

Think about it this way: third row, fifth column is point (5,3), not point (3,5).